# SQL Query Inserting Values

Tags: python, sql, oracle, insert, for-in-loop

I am trying to insert values into database table using Python. I have connected to the database server and have gotten the INSERT INTO sql statement to work, however I cannot figure out how to insert values from a list into my database. I think my problem is simple, and just involves using the for-in loop correctly, but I do not know how to fix it.

The line I need help with is "for i in cur:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Events2013 VALUES (i))")"

Here is part of my code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import fileDb
import g

fileDb.loadTeams()
fileDb.loadEvents()

for event in g.eventList:
    print '%s, %s, %s' % (event.eventName, event.eventType, event.dates)

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('hostname', 1521, 'orcl')
con = cx_Oracle.connect('std15', 'std15', dsn_tns)
cur = con.cursor()

for i in cur:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Events2013 VALUES (i))")

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Events2013")
for result in cur:
    print result

cur.execute("COMMIT")
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: So you're trying to iterate through a cursor?

Answer (score 2):

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Events2013 VALUES (i))")
```

that `i` doesn't automatically expand to the variables (it's passed as a literal `i`)

I imagine you need something like

```
for event in g.eventList:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Events2013 VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')" % (event.eventName, event.eventType, event.dates))
```